# Android ViewRootImpl context leak issue

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

Hi I am doing memory analysis for my application. For that I am trying to identify memory leak of my application. I am getting following type of memory leak.

```
com.sample.activityname has leaked:
* static WindowManagerGlobal.sDefaultWindowManager
* ↳ WindowManagerGlobal.mRoots
* ↳ ArrayList.elementData
* ↳ array Object[].[4]
* ↳ **ViewRootImpl.!(mContext)!**
* ↳ **ContextThemeWrapper.!(mBase)!**
* ↳ activityname
```

What can be the probable reason of **ViewRootImpl.mContext** leaks. I am using leakcanary to identify my leaks. Also I already gone through https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/94 . But not able to get any hint for it.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed memory leaks in my app with heap dumps that looked just like yours.  I eventually traced this back to my usage of the `ProgressDialog` class.  Some of my activities would display a progress dialog using `ProgressDialog.show()` but would call `finish()` before I called `dismiss()` on the shown progress dialog.

Maybe you are displaying some type of ProgressDialog, AlertDialog, or Dialog that is not being dismissed before an activity is destroyed?  Hopefully this helps!